# Accessing the data via controller and methods not working in CodeIgniter while integrating with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I am integrating a Codeigniter project in the Wordpress root folder. While i am trying to access mysql data via controller and method like `http://myapp/project/test` it is displaying error as `Nothing is Found`

At the same time while i set `project/test` as default controller and the mysql data will appearing while accessing via url `http://myapp/`

So, Please tell me how can access data using controller and method.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't configured your .htaccess/CI installation to not include index.php in the URL.

Does http://my.app/index.php/project/test work? If so, just follow the directions here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

> By default, the index.php file will be included in your URLs:
>
> `example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article`
>
> You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:
>
> RewriteEngine on
>   RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt)
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
>
> In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for index.php, images, and robots.txt is treated as a request for your index.php file.